# Parse array expressions in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Does sympy offer a way to work with expressions involving arrays? I'm trying to do something like `expr = sympy_parser('x[0]+x[1]')` or `sympy_parser('sum(x)')` and evaluate that via `expr.subs({'x': [1,2,3]})`.

In the former case, the parser gives an error `TypeError: 'Symbol' object is not subscriptable`. In the latter case it parses, but `subs` doesn't evaluate and just returns the expression `sum(x)` again.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this meets your needs, but you can use sympy `Matrix` objects:

```
from sympy import *

x = Matrix([1, 2, 3])
x[0] + x[1]
sum(x)
```

There is also `MatrixSymbol` for symbolic computations:

```
X = MatrixSymbol('x', 3, 1)
(X[0] + X[1]).subs({X: Matrix([1,2,3])})
sum(X).subs({X: Matrix([1,2,3])})
```